# TYPO3 6.2 ext_autoload with non-namespaced classes

Tags: php, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

I'm trying to create a new Extension on Extbase in TYPO3 6.2 and im failing at including an existing Class/Framework Module.

My ext_autoload.php (ofc located in my extension dir)

```
$extensionPath = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::extPath('couponprinter');

return array(
    'ZendPdf' => $extensionPath . '/Classes/Utility/Zend/Pdf.php',
);
```

I'm trying to load the class in my controller via

```
$pdf = $this->objectManager->create('ZendPdf');
```

But im gettin the error "Could not analyse class:ZendPdf maybe not loaded or no autoloader?"

The Zend class itself has tons of includes which I cant refactor all, so I need the autoloader. Here is a short snippet:

```
/** Internally used classes */
require_once 'Zend/Pdf/Element.php';
require_once 'Zend/Pdf/Element/Array.php';
require_once 'Zend/Pdf/Element/String/Binary.php';
require_once 'Zend/Pdf/Element/Boolean.php';
require_once 'Zend/Pdf/Element/Dictionary.php';
require_once 'Zend/Pdf/Element/Name.php';
require_once 'Zend/Pdf/Element/Null.php';
require_once 'Zend/Pdf/Element/Numeric.php';
require_once 'Zend/Pdf/Element/String.php';

class Zend_Pdf{
// code of the class
}
```

Since TYPO3 6.2 changed some old methods, I can't include anymore. Does anyone have a idea how I can load a not-namespaced class into a extbase extension?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a ext_autoload.php file and fill it with something like

```
<?php
$extensionClassesPath = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::extPath('news') . 'Classes/';

$default = array(
        'tx_news_domain_model_dto_emconfiguration' => $extensionClassesPath . 'Domain/Model/Dto/EmConfiguration.php',
        'tx_news_hooks_suggestreceiver' => $extensionClassesPath . 'Hooks/SuggestReceiver.php',
        'tx_news_hooks_suggestreceivercall' => $extensionClassesPath . 'Hooks/SuggestReceiverCall.php',
        'tx_news_utility_compatibility' => $extensionClassesPath . 'Utility/Compatibility.php',
        'tx_news_utility_importjob' => $extensionClassesPath . 'Utility/ImportJob.php',
        'tx_news_utility_emconfiguration' => $extensionClassesPath . 'Utility/EmConfiguration.php',
        'tx_news_service_cacheservice' => $extensionClassesPath . 'Service/CacheService.php',
);
return $default;
?>
```

Found in the documentation at http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ApiOverview/Autoloading/Index.html

Answer (score 0):

I guess it should be

```
$extensionPath = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::extPath('couponprinter');

return array(
    'zendpdf' => $extensionPath . '/Classes/Utility/Zend/Pdf.php',
);
```

The left side of the array (keys) must be lowercase.